# HP ALM results attachment and status update using python

Tags: python, alm, hp-alm

Challenge : Attach screenshots to Tests in TestLab , update status as PASS/FAIL steps wise (currently updating pass status is enough)

I am expected to write a script in python , to attach test results to the testcases present in test lab, then for each test step Expected result to be set as "As Expected" and pass the TC step by step.

Ie while performing manually, we select the case , click run and then enter "As expected" in expected output area and pass that step, and perfrom this for all teststeps on the test case. This need to be automated. I hav a folder which has Screenshots(similar to TC name), so script shoudl upload the screenshots and update the status.

What I have tried so far :

I was able to connect to alm , with partial testcase name, I was able to pull full testcase name from testplan, but unfortunately i am still struggling to achieve the final goal.

My code so far :

```
import win32com
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import codecs
import re
import json

# Login Credentials
qcServer = "https://almurl.saas.microfocus.com/qcbin/"
qcUser = "my_username"
qcPassword = "pwd"
qcDomain = "domain"
testList = []

testdict = {}
project = "Crew_Management"
  # Do the actual login
td = win32com.client.Dispatch("TDApiOle80.TDConnection.1")
td.InitConnectionEx(qcServer)
td.Login(qcUser,qcPassword)
td.Connect(qcDomain,project)
if td.Connected == True:
    print ("System: Logged in to " +project)
else:
    print ("Connect failed to " +project)

mg = td.TreeManager  # Tree manager
name = ['TC001','TC002','TC003','TC003','TC004','TC005','TC006','TC007','TC008','TC009','TC010','TC011','TC012','TC013','TC014']
folder = mg.NodeByPath('Subject\\Test Factory\\MPG\\MPG Regression Test_Yearly Request\\GUI')
for x in name:
    testList = folder.FindTests(x)
    #print(type(testList))
    print(testList[0].Name)
    print(testList[0].DesStepsNum)

td.Disconnect()
td.Logout()
```

Any help or guidance is much appreciated !

Comment: All you are looking for is available here

https://github.com/macroking/ALM-Integration/blob/master/ALM_Integration_Util.py

Comment: is there any documentation or tutorial to understand that ? I infer that , i can perform the said actions from output xml files from commonly used frameworks. I am quite not sure how to modify it, for my purpose, a documentation or tutorial would be great . I know its too much to ask for.. but i am so stuck

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have working experience in Python. Here I am writing all the different functions needed to complete your task.

**Reference:** https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/ALM_REST_API_TP.html

**Global Variable**

```py
import re
import json
import datetime
import time
import sys
import os, fnmatch
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring, parse
import glob
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests

ALM_USER_NAME = ""
ALM_PASSWORD = ""
ALM_DOMAIN = ""
ALM_URL = ""
AUTH_END_POINT = ALM_URL + "authentication-point/authenticate"
QC_SESSION_END_POINT = ALM_URL + "rest/site-session"
QC_LOGOUT_END_POINT = ALM_URL + "authentication-point/logout"
ALM_MIDPOINT = "rest/domains/" + ALM_DOMAIN + "/projects/"
PATH_SEP = os.path.sep
```

**Login Function**

```py
    def alm_login(self):
        """
            Function    :   alm_login
            Description :   Authenticate user
            Parameters  :   global parameter
                            alm_username     -   ALM User
                            alm_password     -   ALM Password
        """
        response = self.alm_session.post(AUTH_END_POINT,
                                         auth=HTTPBasicAuth(ALM_USER_NAME, ALM_PASSWORD))
        if response.status_code == 200:
            response = self.alm_session.post(QC_SESSION_END_POINT)
            if response.status_code == 200 | response.status_code == 201:
                print "ALM Authentication successful"
            else:
                print "Error: ", response.staus_code
        else:
            print "Error: ", response.staus_code
        self.alm_session.headers.update({'Accept':'application/json',
                                         'Content-Type': 'application/xml'})
        return
```

**Logout Function**

After the logout method is successful the cookie should expire

```py
    def alm_logout(self):
        '''
            Function    :   alm_logout
            Description :   terminate user session
            Parameters  :   No Parameters
        '''
        response = self.alm_session.post(QC_LOGOUT_END_POINT)
        print "Logout successful", response.headers.get('Expires'), response.status_code
        return
```

**Get Test Set Folder**

If the test cases span across multiple test suites then it is better to get the test set folder first and find the necessary test suite.

```py
    def find_test_set_folder(self):
        '''
            Function    :   find_test_set_folder
            Description :   This sends a couple of http request and authenticate the user
            Parameters  :   1 Parameter
                            test_set_path    -   ALM test set path
        '''
        json_str = json.loads(self.find_folder_id(self.test_set_path.split("\\"), "test-set-folders"
                                                  , 0, "id"))
        if 'entities' in json_str:
            return create_key_value(json_str['entities'][0]['Fields'])['id']
        else:
            return create_key_value(json_str['Fields'])['id']
```

**Get Folder Id**

This method will help you find the Test Suite Folder ID or Test Plan Folder Id.

```py
    def find_folder_id(self, arrfolder, str_api, parent_id, fields):
        '''
            Function    :   find_folder_id
            Description :   This sends a couple of http request and authenticate the user
            Parameters  :   1 Parameter
                            test_set_path    -   ALM test set path
        '''
        for foldername in arrfolder:
            payload = {"query": "{name['" + foldername + "'];parent-id[" + str(parent_id) + "]}",
                       "fields": fields}
            response = self.alm_session.get(ALM_URL + ALM_MIDPOINT + "/" + str_api, params=payload)
            obj = json.loads(response.text)
            if obj["TotalResults"] >= 1:
                parent_id = get_field_value(obj['entities'][0]['Fields'], "id")
                # print("folder id of " + foldername + " is " + str(parent_id))
            else:
                # print("Folder " + foldername + " does not exists")
                inputdata = dict()
                inputdata['Type'] = str_api[0:len(str_api) - 1]
                inputdata['name'] = foldername
                inputdata['parent-id'] = str(parent_id)
                data = generate_xml_data(inputdata)
                response = self.alm_session.post(ALM_URL + ALM_MIDPOINT + "/" + str_api, data=data)
                obj = json.loads(response.text)
                if response.status_code == 200 | response.status_code == 201:
                    parent_id = get_field_value(obj['Fields'], "id")
                    # print("folder id of " + foldername + " is " + str(parent_id))
        return response.text
```

**Create Run Instance**

Before updating the testing status, we must create a run instance for the test.

```py
def create_run_instance(self, test_set_id, test_map):
        '''
            Function    :   create_run_instance
            Description :   Create new run instances
            Parameters  :   Test Set Id
        '''
        str_api = "test-instances"
        fields = "id,test-id,test-config-id,cycle-id"
        payload = {"query": "{cycle-id['" + test_set_id + "']}", "fields": fields,
                   "page-size": 5000}
        response = self.alm_session.get(ALM_URL + ALM_MIDPOINT + "/" + str_api, params=payload)
        obj = json.loads(response.text)

        run_instance_post = "<Entities>"
        for entity in obj["entities"]:
            run_name = re.sub('[-:]', '_',
                              'automation_' + datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime(
                                  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
            temp_map = create_key_value(entity["Fields"])
            _test_id = int(temp_map['test-id'])
            self.parser_temp_dic[_test_id]['testcycl-id'] = temp_map['id']
            self.parser_temp_dic[_test_id]['test-config-id'] = temp_map['test-config-id']
            self.parser_temp_dic[_test_id]['test-id'] = temp_map['test-id']
            self.parser_temp_dic[_test_id]['cycle-id'] = temp_map['cycle-id']
            # parser_temp_dic[int(temp_map['test-id'])]['status'].sort()
            status = "Passed"
            if 'Failed' in self.parser_temp_dic[int(temp_map['test-id'])]['status']:
                status = 'Failed'
            self.parser_temp_dic[int(temp_map['test-id'])]['final-status'] = status

            inputdata = dict()
            inputdata['Type'] = 'run'
            inputdata['name'] = run_name
            inputdata['owner'] = ALM_USER_NAME
            inputdata['test-instance'] = str(1)
            inputdata['testcycl-id'] = str(temp_map['id'])
            inputdata['cycle-id'] = str(temp_map['cycle-id'])
            inputdata['status'] = 'Not Completed'
            inputdata['test-id'] = temp_map['test-id']
            inputdata['subtype-id'] = 'hp.qc.run.MANUAL'
            data = generate_xml_data(inputdata)
            run_instance_post = run_instance_post + data

        self.bulk_operation("runs", run_instance_post + "</Entities>", True, "POST")
        return
```

**Update Run Instance**

```py
    def update_run_instance(self, test_set_id):
        '''
            Function    :   update_run_instance
            Description :   Update the test status in run instances
            Parameters  :   No input parameter
        '''
        fields = "id,test-id"
        payload = {"query": "{cycle-id['" + test_set_id + "']}", "fields": fields,
                   "page-size": 5000}
        response = self.alm_session.get(ALM_URL + ALM_MIDPOINT + "/runs", params=payload)
        obj = json.loads(response.text)

        run_instance_put = "<Entities>"
        for entity in obj["entities"]:
            if len(entity["Fields"]) != 1:
                temp_map = create_key_value(entity["Fields"])
                self.parser_temp_dic[int(temp_map['test-id'])]['run-id'] = temp_map['id']
                inputdata = dict()
                inputdata['Type'] = 'run'
                inputdata['id'] = str(temp_map['id'])
                intermediate_ = self.parser_temp_dic[int(temp_map['test-id'])]['testcycl-id']
                inputdata['testcycl-id'] = str(intermediate_)
                inputdata['status'] = self.parser_temp_dic[int(temp_map['test-id'])]['final-status']
                data = generate_xml_data(inputdata)
                run_instance_put = run_instance_put + data

        self.bulk_operation("runs", run_instance_put + "</Entities>", True, "PUT")
        return
```

**Upload Result File**

Uploading file to any object in ALM

```py
    def upload_result_file(self, test_set_id, report_file):
        '''
            Function    :   upload_result_file
            Description :   Upload test result to ALM
        '''
        payload = open(report_file, 'rb')
        headers = {}
        headers['Content-Type'] = "application/octet-stream"
        headers['slug'] = "test-results" + report_file[report_file.rfind(".")+1: ]
        response = self.alm_session.post(ALM_URL + ALM_MIDPOINT + "/test-sets/" +
                                         str(test_set_id) + "/attachments/",
                                         headers=headers, data=payload)
        if not (response.status_code == 200 or response.status_code == 201):
            print "Attachment step failed!", response.text, response.url, response.status_code
        return
```

**Bulk Operation**

This is a helper that allows us to POST an array of data.

```py
    def bulk_operation(self, str_api, data, isbulk, request_type):
        '''
            Function    :   Post Test Case / Test Instance
            Description :   Generic function to post multiple entities.
            Parameters  :   3 parameters
                            str_api          -   End point name
                            data             -   Actual data to post
                            isbulk           -   True or False
        '''
        response = None
        headers = {}
        try:
            if isbulk:
                headers['Content-Type'] = "application/xml;type = collection"
            if request_type == 'POST':
                response = self.alm_session.post(ALM_URL + ALM_MIDPOINT + "/" + str_api, data=data,
                                                 headers=headers)
            elif request_type == 'PUT':
                response = self.alm_session.put(ALM_URL + ALM_MIDPOINT + "/" + str_api, data=data,
                                                headers=headers)
        except Exception as err:
            print err
        if response.status_code == 200 | response.status_code == 201:
            return response.text
        return response
```

Comment: I have a question here, regarding the file size of the attachment. I tried to upload a 2mb file it failed, showed an error. Is there a way to upload heavy files ?

Comment: Size limit is managed by ALM admin, have a conversation with your ALM Admin. He should be able to increase the limit after understanding your usecase.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this code
https://github.com/arunprabusamy/Python-Libraries/blob/main/alm_RestAPI/almLib.py

You need to send only three values - Test Set ID (Cycle ID), ALM Test ID & Execution Status. The library automatically builds the json payload and creates a test run and update result.